# How to get the characteristic equation of $AB^{-1}?$

Tags: matrices

Problem where it was likely needed : If $A, B$ and $A + B$ are all $n × n$ invertible matrices of order $3 \times 3$  satisfying $A^{-1} + B^{-1} = (A + B)^{-1}$ and $|AB^{-1}| \in \mathbb{R}$ (belongs to real numbers)  then the value of $|A|/|B|?$
My progress : multiplying by $A+B$ both sides left side we get $AB^{-1} + BA^{-1}$ = $-I$ (i) , now as its a $3 \times 3$
matrix $(AB^{-1})$ max degree characteristic equation it may form is of three degrees but here how one convinces that this is the characteristic equation or not (i)? Also what is the use of the given condition of $|AB^{-1}| \in \mathbb{R}$? [By characteristic equation from I mean this one: let $X$ be $AB^{-1}$, then $X^2 + I+X = 0$ is the equation one gets by multipying by $X$ again in (i)]

Comment: The characteristic equation of $AB^{-1}$ must be of degree $3$ because $AB^{-1}$ has size $3 \times 3$. However, the **minimal polynomial** of $AB^{-1}$ must divide the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: Hmm correct thanks for correcting it Ben Grossmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now as its a $3 \times 3$
> matrix $(AB^{-1})$ max degree characteristic equation it may form is of three degrees but here how one convinces that this is the characteristic equation or not (i)?

I have no idea how to answer this question. However, here's an answer to the original question:

> If $A, B$ and $A + B$ are all $n × n$ invertible matrices of order $3 \times 3$  satisfying $A^{-1} + B^{-1} = (A + B)^{-1}$ and $|AB^{-1}| \in \mathbb{R}$ (belongs to real numbers)  then the value of $|A|/|B|?$

As you have already found, $X = AB^{-1}$ must satisfy the equation $X^2 + X + I = 0$. It follows that $Xv = \lambda v$ for some non-zero $v \in \Bbb C^3$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$, then we have
$$
(X^2 + X + I)v = 0 \implies (\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1)v = 0 \implies \lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 = 0.
$$
Conclude that the eigenvalues of $X$ must be equal to $\lambda_1 = \frac 12 (1 + i \sqrt{3})$ or $\lambda_2 = \frac 12 (1 - i \sqrt{3})$. Thus, there are four possible sets of eigenvalues that $X$ could have (corresponding to the different possible multiplicities of $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$). Because the determinant of $X$ is the product of its eigenvalues, it must be that
$$
\det(X) = \lambda_1^3 = 1, \quad \det(X) = \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2 = \lambda_1, \\ \det(X) = \lambda_1\lambda_2^2 = \lambda_2, \quad \text{or } \det(X) = \lambda_2^3 = 1.
$$
From the fact that $\det(X) \in \Bbb R$, we can deduce that $\det(X) = 1$.

Comment: Hmm nicely explained :) thanks Ben Grossmann

Comment: just one doubt related to your answer ,is it necessary that X^2 ,X both have same eigenvectors? @Ben Grossmann

Comment: @Orion_Pax If $Xv = \lambda v$, then
$$
X^2 v = X(Xv) = X(\lambda v) = \lambda Xv = \lambda^2 v.
$$
So, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $X$, then it must be an eigenvector of $X^2$.

Comment: Hmm got it thanks @Ben_Grossmann